# How to write Python script to merge two same key value pair dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting  `{1: 200, 2: 200}` as output

I need output like `{1: 100, 2: 200,1: 100, 2: 200}`

```
d1 = {1: 100, 2: 200}     
d2 = {1: 200, 2: 200}     
d = d1.copy()     
d.update(d2)       
print(d)
```

Comment: Dictionaries in Python have unique keys. You can't duplicate them (ie have two entries of 1).

Comment: Its not possible to merge the above two dictionaries?

Comment: when we write d={1:2,2:3,1:4} it takes 4 as value for 1 no. this dictionary has two items with 1 as key no

Comment: Just like the physical english dictionary, the programming data structure must have unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys. You can approach this way where you can put all values for a particular key in a list.

```
d1 = {1: 100, 2: 200}     
d2 = {1: 200, 2: 200}
ds = [d1, d2]
d = {}
for k in d1.iterkeys():
    d[k] = [d[k] for d in ds]

print d
```

The above code will result,

```
{1: [100, 200], 2: [200, 200]}
```